# Column 'CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH' does not belong to table

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have an error with a software made in Vb.Net. I can't figure out where to look, and google isn't helping me neither.
Can I look somewhere to try something?

```
System.ArgumentException: Column 'CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH' does not belong to table .
   at System.Data.DataColumnCollection.Remove(String name)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ISSchemaProvider.GetColumns(String[] restrictions)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.SchemaProvider.GetSchemaInternal(String collection, String[] restrictions)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ISSchemaProvider.GetSchemaInternal(String collection, String[] restrictions)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.SchemaProvider.GetSchema(String collection, String[] restrictions)
```

Comment: the tag of the question should be VB.net

Comment: Difficult to say anything without code to look at

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are working with DataTable and the column you are trying to use does not belong to it. CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH  is the column name and it is just confusing.

```
Dim tbl As New DataTable
tbl.Columns.Remove("aa")
```

result

```
Message=Column 'aa' does not belong to table .
  Source=System.Data
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.DataColumnCollection.Remove(String name)
       at dbpokusy.net.Module1.AddConstantToQuery() in C:\...
```

Comment: CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH is a default column in information_schema table, I'm not using it

Comment: @Kreker: Have a look at this https://phalangermysql.svn.codeplex.com/svn/2.0/MySql.Data/MySql/Data/MySqlClient/ISSchemaProvider.cs. There is function GetColumns which is probaby the one causing problem. I am not an expert in MySql maybe you should change tags to mysqlclient and .net. The question is not related to vb only.